# How to fix this SQL query issue in postgres db?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query that must return a list of overdue rentals and know I write this query in Postgres as below:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(customer.last_name, ', ' , customer.first_name) AS customer,
    address.phone, film.title
FROM 
    rental 
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN 
    address ON customer.address_id = address.address_id
INNER JOIN 
    inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
INNER JOIN 
    film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE 
    rental.return_date IS NULL
    AND rental_date + INTERVAL film.rental_duration DAY < CURRENT_DATE
LIMIT 5;
```

but when I run this query in pgAdmin, I get this error :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "film"
>   LINE 8:     AND rental_date + INTERVAL film.rental_duration DAY < CU...

What is the problem?

Comment: I think, you need to give the table name of column of that rental_date

Comment: Does PostgreSql know such property as "CURRENT_DATE"?
I suppose, you should use "now()" function there.

Comment: I change  to rental.rental_date But the problem was not resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax for interval addition is something like this: `select current_date + interval '1 day'`. You are missing some apostrophes, so it wont work this way.

It should be okay if you change your line 8 to look like this:

`AND rental_date + film.rental_duration < CURRENT_DATE`

If `rental_duration` is not an integer type, go like this:

`AND rental_date + film.rental_duration::int < CURRENT_DATE`

If rental_date is a timestamp:

`AND rental_date + interval '1 day' * film.rental_duration < CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: my rental_duration is short type and rental_date is Timestamp type

Comment: know show error  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone + integer
LINE 8:     AND rental.rental_date + film.rental_duration::INT < CUR...

Comment: Updated the answer.